# How do you search for a name in a txt file and add a mark next to it in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, io

I have a project that requires me to make menu;

1. Enter name and input it to txt file;
2. Search for name and input mark(s) next to it(each time you can only enter one mark
3. Save the name and mark to a 2-D array

I am able to do the first task, but I can't do the second task.

Here is my code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
File f = new java.io.File("Data.txt");
String champ;
String grade;
int i = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
System.out.println("Search for a name");
champ = s.nextLine();
while(scanner.hasNext())
{
  String champion = scanner.nextLine();
  if (champion .equals (champ))
  {
    System.out.println("grade?");
    grade = s.nextLine();
    out.print(grade);
  }
}
out.close();
```

Let say I have **Leo George David**(Not on the same line) on my file

If I type Leo it searches for the name "Leo" if "Leo" exist, it will ask for the grade. If a type 95 then, it should be:

Leo 95

George

David

But I got this instead

Leo

George

David

95

Also, How do you save it to 2-D ArrayList(increase depend on how many marks they input).

For example:

if I have this on my file

Leo 95 65 78 45

George 34 54 76 45 32

David 98 97 45 76 43

The 2-D array should look like the format above.

How do you save Leo data to name[0][i] and when the scanner know that it is next line then it will create a new row name[1][i];(i is the number of marks).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is your homework assignment so I will give you a few hints:
1. Its much easier to read file and temporary save data on list then update/add something on list and again rewrite in file.(Considering that you are playing with small files which you do)
2. Here is how you can read data and put it into 2D ArrayList and print it as you wanted:

```
List<List<String>> column = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> row;
    String[] tmp = null;
    // reading file and saving text to list which you can later update
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Data.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    for (String line : lines) {

        tmp = line.trim().split("\\s+");
        if (tmp != null) {
            row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {

                row.add(tmp[i]);
            }
            column.add(row);
        }
    }
    //Here is example of how you go thru 2D ArrayList and print elements
    for(int i = 0; i<column.size();i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < column.get(i).size();j++){
            System.out.print(column.get(i).get(j)+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

What is left for you is to find how to rewrite data from list to file every time you finish updating.